# Excel: 2 sheets, populate the matching cells from one sheet with the values from the other

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question has been asked and aswered before in other forms. But, I have no experience at all with Excel and I don't know how to adapt the other answers to my use case. If someone would be able to help me in my use case, I would be deeply grateful.

My use case: I have a dropshipping store and I need to update my stock using Excel files. My stock update file has two columns: SKU and Stock. My suppliers send me stock files with similar columns, but not all products from my supplier files are listed in my shop and the order in their files is different.

What I would like is to be able to make a workbook with two sheets:

- My stock

[image]

- Supplier Stock

[image]

Then, to be able to change the column "Stock" from the sheet "My Stock" with the values found in the "Supllier stock" sheet for that SKU. If a SKU is not found, ignore. For example, check "Supplier Stock" for SKU1 and update SKU1 in "My stock" with the found value.

Is this possible? It would save me a lot of time.
Thank you verry much.

Edit:
"Foo"and "Bar"are examples of SKUs that need to be ignored, as they have no match in "My stock"sheet.

Comment: what about "Foo" and "Bar"?

Comment: "Foo" and "Bar" ar examples of SKU's that need to be ignored, because they are not in "My stock" sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following formula in `Cell B2` of sheet `My Stock`

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE),"")
```

or

```
=INDEX('Supplier Stock'!$B$2:$B$8,MATCH(A2,'Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$A$8,0))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i get the error "The formula you typed contains an error".

Comment: @HoriaRudan - Try `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$B$8;2;FALSE);"")`

Comment: Tried both ways, but I get the same error. Could you please send my your file? Thank you!

Comment: @HoriaRudan - Oops! I missed `,` after `A2`. Try `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$B$8;2;FALSE);"")`

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same error. Is it possible to send me your file, wia wetransfer or something? Thank you verry much!

Comment: @HoriaRudan is the name of the sheet from Your supplier `Supplier Stock`?

Comment: @krib - Sheet name seems okay as per the screenshot link in comment above.

Comment: Yes, the name si Supplier Stock.

Comment: could it be that there is regional differences as in not a `,` but a `;`?

Comment: @HoriaRudan - Could you attach error screen shot using formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$B$8;2;FALSE);"")` as I suggested above.

Comment: @Mrig saw now. But shouldn't the index formula be `=INDEX('Supplier Stock'!$A$2:$B$8` ?

Comment: @krib - Nope! For index formula it should `=INDEX('Supplier Stock'!$B$2:$B$8...`.

Comment: Ok, my bad. It seemes my Excel uses pipes instead of commas. Replaced all commas with pipes and it works great. Thank you. Marking it as solved.

Comment: @HoriaRudan - Great!